# NullReferenceException when accessing to an element of array from another script

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, gameobject

I have two objects: **Tile** and **TileGrid** which have their own scripts.
TileGrid can generate a 2d array of Tiles. Then I am trying to attach every Tile around the Tile in the script for every Tile, so all of my Tiles will have a reference to their 'neighbors'. I use a dictionary.
To do that I wrote a function which is accessing TileGrid's 2d array of Tiles.
Unfortunately, a **NullReferenceException** is thrown.

TileGridScript.cs

```
public class TileGridScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[][] tileGrid;
    // Other properties ...
    public void MakeGrid(int width = 64, int height = 64)
    {
        tileGrid = new GameObject[width][];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            tileGrid[x] = new GameObject[height];
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                // !!! Instantiating tiles !!!
                tileGrid[x][y] = Instantiate(grassPrefab, new Vector2(x - width / 2, y - height / 2), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
        // !!! Call the function to connect Tiles !!!
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                tileGrid[x][y].GetComponent<TileScript>().AttchTile(this);
    }
}
```

TileScript.cs

```
public class TileScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dictionary<string, GameObject> connectedTiles;
    // Other properties ...
    private void Start()
    {
        connectedTiles = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>(8);
    }
    public void AttchTile (TileGridScript tileGridScript)
    {
        for (int biasx = -1; biasx < 2; biasx++)
        {
            for (int biasy = -1; biasy < 2; biasy++)
            {

                switch (biasx)
                {
                    case -1: // L
                        switch (biasy)
                        {
                            case -1: // D
                                try
                                {
                                    // !!! Catches the error here !!!
                                    connectedTiles["DL"] = tileGridScript.tileGrid[(int)position.x + biasx][(int)position.y + biasy]; 
                                }
                                catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
                                break;
                        }
                    // etc for every Tile. P.S. DL means Down and Left.
                    // in this way I add all 8 Tiles around that
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameManager.cs

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tileGridPrefab;
    // Other properties...
    void Start()
    {
        // !!! Here I generate the Tile Grid !!!
        tileGridPrefab.GetComponent<TileGridScript>().MakeGrid(24, 16);
    }
}
```

I tried to write this function in TileGrid's script and call it from that.
If I don't initialize a dictionary in Start() it does okay. Then when I access it from another script, it falls with the same error.
I tried to change the order of these scripts in the editor.

What is the reason for the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Here `connectedTiles["DL"] = tileGridScript.tileGrid[(int)position.x + biasx][(int)position.y + biasy];`. I added a comment there. Of course I know what it is. But I don't understand why I get it.

Comment: As you can see from my code, I initialize all Tiles in the array before calling the attach function. Still I get this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Start()` is calling after `AttachTile()`.

I should use `Awake()` instead. I get **TileGrid** object in `Awake()` and then can use it in `AttachTile()` function.

Comment: Very typical example for a race condition .. I use a simple rule: Whatever only depends on me (e.g. getting components, setting default values etc) do in `Awake`; whatever depends on other components, objects etc do in `Start`